# How to find entries in vertical table that have one column zeroed out without using Pivot

Tags: sql

I'm working with a large vertical database with millions of entries and need to find part number & revision combinations where every Mvalue is zero.

[image]

In this simplified example, the result should be Part number 1234 Rev 0

The vertical structure is causing me trouble but I assumed pivoting the data would be a bad idea due to the database size.

Is there a way to do this without a Pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select pn, rev
from t
group by pn, rev
having min(mvalue) = 0 and max(mvalue) = 0
```

Comment: ah, thank you.  The `group by` is what I was missing.  What do you think about using `SUM(mvalue)` instead of min/max?

Comment: @AutomateThis `SUM()` can work, if you are sure there are no negative numbers that could cancel out positive ones.

Comment: Excellent point.  I just tried it and it worked great with quick return.  Thank you